# Slow WiFi on Ubntu 15.04 with Realtek RTL8192EE

Tags: wireless, 15.04, realtek-wireless

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 15.04 in dual boot with windows 8.1 on my ThinkPad T450. The wifi connection in Ubuntu is much slower than in Windows.

Is there a way to fix this? I don't know how to provide precise information on my system, so if needed please tell me where to find this info.

EDIT: the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` is

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192EE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:818b]
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:001b]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8192ee
```

EDIT: switching to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS solved the problem, but after an apt-get update it came back again. Now the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` is

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192EE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:818b]
Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:001b]
Kernel driver in use: r8192ee
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to install a new driver for Realtek wireless adapters.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Unfortunately this gave just a marginal improvement...

Comment: This worked for me.  I get some slow spikes but I get them in windows too.  This fixed the massive slow-stops I was getting.  I can use Ubuntu as my primary os now.  Thanks.